# Why I can't see notebook in project Watson Studio?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

I've created a project in Watson Studio, then want to create a Jupiter notebook, however, can't see this feature. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing entitlements meaning you have either created watson studio in other region than US region as i see you are hitting US region watson studio url https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/.
Go to IBM Cloud Dashboard => https://cloud.ibm.com/ and check which region has your watson studio service and then open that service and click manage -> Get started that will take you to right region. An example would be if you have service in eu-gb, then url would look like https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/
Alternatively you can also delete the service from IBM Cloud and create the service in your desired region.

There are two more region Watson Studio is available:-
Tokyo:- https://jp-tok.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/
Franfurt:- https://eu-de.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/

Answer (score 0):

Goto my assets, and add new asset under the code editor section