# How to add Notebook in Asset type in projects?

Tags: websphere, jupyter, ibm-watson

I want to create a Jupyter notebook in IBM Watson studio. When I click on Add project, In asset type there is no option of Notebook. So what should I do? I want to create a notebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957237/why-i-cant-see-notebook-in-project-watson-studio/61975283

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information ?

- Is it in IBM Cloud or your own local instance ?
- You should create a project and then click on "Add to project". You should have the Notebook option.
- Send a screenshot of the part where you are stuck.